# JQ duplicate results in output json

Tags: jq

I have the following input json for jq:

```json
{
  "records": [
    {
      "uuid": "14e20b5a-6619-11ec-a838-0050568168f7",
      "nas": {
        "path": "/data/nlp/datasets/ds0"
      }
    },
    {
      "uuid": "799ce816-656c-11ec-a838-0050568168f7",
      "nas": {
        "path": "/data/nlp/datasets/ds1"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

What is the reason the following jq duplicate the results:

```
[{junction:.records[].nas.path}+{uuid:.records[].uuid}]
```

Result:

```json
[
  {
    "junction": "/data/nlp/datasets/ds0",
    "uuid": "14e20b5a-6619-11ec-a838-0050568168f7"
  },
  {
    "junction": "/data/nlp/datasets/ds1",
    "uuid": "14e20b5a-6619-11ec-a838-0050568168f7"
  },
  {
    "junction": "/data/nlp/datasets/ds0",
    "uuid": "799ce816-656c-11ec-a838-0050568168f7"
  },
  {
    "junction": "/data/nlp/datasets/ds1",
    "uuid": "799ce816-656c-11ec-a838-0050568168f7"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Both `{junction:.records[].nas.path}`and `{uuid:.records[].uuid}` produce a stream of two objects each due to the iteration caused by `.records[]`. Adding up the cartesian product, this totals to four objects.

If you want to iterate jut once, pull out the iterator `.records[]` up front to define a common input context for the subsequent filter:

```
.records[] | {junction:.nas.path} + {uuid:.uuid}
```

This can then further be simplified to

```
.records[] | {junction:.nas.path, uuid}
```

```json
{
  "junction": "/data/nlp/datasets/ds0",
  "uuid": "14e20b5a-6619-11ec-a838-0050568168f7"
}
{
  "junction": "/data/nlp/datasets/ds1",
  "uuid": "799ce816-656c-11ec-a838-0050568168f7"
}
```

which is presumably what you were looking for.

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/2qL6XRIQ3N)

Comment: Put brackets `[…]` around the (whole) filter to turn the output stream of two objects into an array of two objects: `[.records[] | {junction:.nas.path, uuid}]`.